# RestSharp Redirection and Authentication 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc, heroku, neo4j, basic-authentication, restsharp

I am trying to make a REST request to a Neo4j instance hosted via heroku. The server is setup with Basic Authentication.

This is the url I was provided with from Heroku (**notice the trailing slash**): http://username:password@instance.hosted.neo4j.org:123/db/data**/**

I'm using RestSharp to connect to this instance. However, RestSharp will remove the trailing slash. [Code](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestClient.cs#L271). The resulting url becomes: http://username:password@instance.hosted.neo4j.org:123/db/data

This results in a `HTTP 301` to (**notice the trailing slash**): http://username:password@instance.hosted.neo4j.org:123/db/data/

The problem is that the Authorization Header is not persisted across redirects [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx). This redirect results in `HTTP 401`.

Are there any obvious ways around this? I've tried the following:

- Provide 2 trailing slashes `/db/data//` so RestSharp only removed one slash but leaves one remaining. This doesn't work as other requests have invalid formats: `/db/data//query/stuff`
- Use `CredentialCache` class. This works but results in 2 requests per action (One for the 401 challenge, another one for the response)
- `IAuthenticationModlue` - Found minimal info on this in MSDN but after trying a custom class, this will still result in the double hop issue noted previously.
- <s>Change the initial rest request to be `new RestRequest("/", Method.GET);` instead of `new RestRequest("", Method.GET);` - the only probelm is I don't want to modify the Open Source project that is in between my app and RestSharp for my specific needs.</s> RestSharp removes all ending slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From pete at the Google Group:

> One, somewhat annoying, workaround for requesting the "root resource" is 
>   to use: new RestRequest ("/ "), the trailing whitespace will prevent 
>   RestSharp from trimming the slash, but will be ignored by (most) 
>   servers.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/restsharp/8mBmaXksmsg

Comment: Note: This doesn't work with query string parameters, it gets turned into `/%20?` which breaks.